# what is the difference between ScrollView, ListView, RecyclerView and WebView?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to know when to use ScrollView or ListView or RecyclerView and also Can we use WebView for building an app?

Comment: ScrollView Just to scroll. If you put lots of buttons in LinearLayout or any other, below one by one. You can not see the whole buttons. But If you put those buttons in ScrollView, you can just scroll and view all of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## SCROLLVIEW

```
ScrollView is used to put different or same child views or layouts and the all can be scrolled.
```

## Listview

```
ListView is used to put same child view or layout as multiple items. All these items are also scrollable.

Simply ScrollView is for both homogeneous and heterogeneous collection. ListView is for only homogeneous collection.
```

## What is RecyclerView?

```
The RecyclerView widget is a more advanced and flexible version of ListView.
```

## Why RecyclerView?

```
RecyclerView is a container for displaying large data sets that can be scrolled very efficiently by maintaining a limited number of views.
```

## When you should use RecyclerView?

```
You can use the RecyclerView widget when you have data collections whose elements 
changes at runtime based on user action or network events.
```

## WEBVIEW

```
WebView in Android turns the application into a web application. It comes from 
android.webkit.WebView. Here, the WebView class is an extension of Android's View 
class which is used to show the web pages. WebView doesn't include all the features 
of Web-browser-like navigation controls or an address bar etc.
```